# "JSON.stingify is not a function" DataTables When Making Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable, datatables

I've tried a bunch of things.

I have a button with the id `save` that I'm trying to put `.selected` rows into JSON format.

Here's my datatable initialization.

```
<script>
//    var table;
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable(
        {
"order": [],
                "processing": true,
             "searching": false,
             "paging": false, 
             "autowidth": true,
             'select': {
 'style': 'multi'
          },
 "columnDefs": [
    { orderable: false, targets: '_all' }
]
   });
```

If I put the on click function within the `$(document).ready(function()`

```
$(document).on('click','#save',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var data = table.rows(['.selected']).data().toArray();
var json = JSON.stingify( data );
console.log( JSON.stringify(data) );
var json = JSON.stingify( data );
console.log( (json) );
} );

} );
```

My console returns both the proper format, and the `JSON.stingify is not a function` error.

> [["My","Selected","Row","Row","Row","your","boat"]]
>
> Uncaught TypeError: JSON.stingify is not a function

I've tried to put the click event inside a function

```
$('#save').click(recordjourney);
```

And put the `recordjourney` function outside the `$(document).ready(function()` DataTables intialization.

But cannot get the datatable to reinitalize the rows.

```
function recordjourney() {
 var data = table.rows(['.selected']).data().toArray();
```

> Uncaught TypeError: table.rows is not a function

I've tried redrawing it

```
      $('#example').DataTable().draw();
```

I've tried to reinitialize the table

```
var table = $('#example');
```

/

```
var table = rows.closest('table').dataTable();
```

and using the api.

```
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var rows = table.DataTable().row( tr );
    
    table.api()
         .row( rows )
         .remove()
         .draw();
```

All result in errors of different but similar sorts, not being able to find `table`, or `rows`, or `table.rows`

Why can I console.log my JSON.stringify fine, but not put it in a variable?
How can I get the onclick event to register the rows to JSON stringify the data coming from the datatable?

Comment: It's `stringify`, not `stingify`.

Comment: Oh, right, okay then.

Comment: A mere googling would have solved your issue. Anyways, kudos for posting a full fledged problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo here, `stingify` is not a function its `stringify`

-Help

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, just a typo

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify({ a: "b" }));
```